Can a chain drive sytem be used to increase torque?
My understanding:
To increase torque, we use a small driving gear and a big driven gear. This increases torque because the distance between the small gear and the large gear is increased as evident from the following formula:
Torque = Force * Distance

Question:
If distance is what matters for torque (keeping the applied force constant), can using both driver and driven gear of the same size and increasing the distance between them using a chain drive system (like we have in a bicycle) increase torque?

what is the distance  in the formula? ... it is definitely not the distance between the gears ... the ratio of gear diameters is what matters ... it's the same as any pulley system or gear system

It is the distance between the point where force is applied and the point at which we want the work to be done. For example when we use a wrench to open a bolt, the length of wrench in this case is the distance.

In case of a gear based system consider an example where there is a small driver gear attached to a motor shaft and a big driven gear attached to a rod. Now distance is the distance between the center of small gear and big gear.

Yes but only the radius/diameter of the gears changed. The chain drive works exactly the same way the radius/diameter difference between the sprockes cases the difference not the length of the chain. This is why your bike has differently sozed sprocket wheels.


My understanding: Torque = Force * Distance

It may help if you reword that to,
$$Torque = Force \times radius$$
where Force is at right angles to the radius and radius is the distance between the centre of rotation and the point of application of the force.

... can using both driver and driven gear of the same size and increasing the distance between them using a chain drive system (like we have in a bicycle) increase torque?

No, not at all. The torque will only be affected if there is a difference in the number of teeth on each gear or chain wheel.

In response to comment:

For example there are 2 big gears of same size driver and driven (directly in contact and no chain system involved). Now According to your updated formula, the radius will be the radius of the driven gear.

No, you have to take both gears into account.

Figure 1. Image based on Wikimedia.

Assume gear 1 (red) is driving gear 2 (green).
Assume we're in a state of constant speed (which could be zero speed). F1 = F2. Otherwise, if F2 > F1 the system would slow down and stop or if F2 < F1 the system would accelerate.
Since $T_1 = F_1R_1$ and $T_2 = F_2R_2$ we can rearrange to
$$F_1 = F_2$$
$$\frac {T_1}{R_1} = \frac {T_2}{R_2}$$
$$T_2 = \frac{R_2}{R_1}T_1$$

So the torque of gear 2 will be proportional to the gear 1 torque times the ratio R2:R1.

In this case, how and why does size of driver gear has any impact of torque because the distance between the force applied(point where both teeth meet and the point of rotation(center of the driven gear) remains the same regardless of the size of driver gear?

No. You are forgetting that the torque applied by the first gear depends on its radius.

"The torque will only be affected if there is a difference in the number of teeth on each gear" what is the reason behind this? For example there are 2 big gears of same size driver and driven(directly in contact and no chain system involved). Now According to your updated formula, the radius will be the radius of the driven gear. In this case, how and why does size of driver gear has any impact of torque because the distance between the force applied(point where both teeth meet and the point of rotation(center of the driven gear) remains the same regardless of the size of driver gear right?.

it would be better to draw the free body diagrams as separate drawings as it makes this clearer to understand

@joojaa, go ahead and post with separate drawings. I've kind of gone as far as I want with this one.

@Transistor Got the idea! Thanks for the efforts. :)

your conceptual picture is wrong. torque multiplication/RPM division occurs in chain, gear, and belt drives because of the diameter ratio between the input and output wheels. this has nothing to do with the distance between them.

Edit suggestion: change "diameter difference" to "diameter ratio".

@transistor, agree- will edit.
